# How do I access a logged in users phone number in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.8, I want to access the logged in users phone number , is there any quick way of doing this? Without using:

```
$this->User->find(all,conditions);
conditions=array(Authcomponent::user('id')== 'Profile.user_id')
```

I don't want to use the above code, is there a code like:

`$this->AuthComponent::user->profile`

Just a like of code that I can use to get the phone number of a user which is in the profile table.

Comment: @ Sewlor , thanks, but please look at the code below  echo $number[0]['Proposal']['user_id'];, how can i remove [0] from the array above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that in view , just do:

```
$phone = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.phone');
```

In case you want this in controller:

```
$phone = $this->Auth->User('phone')
```