# how to show username when user is logged in with cakephp?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to cakephp and I can't show the username when a user is logged.
here is my code from my default page:

```
    <?php if ($loggedIn): ?>
    <p id="happytext"> Connecté en tant que </p>

    <!---Test--->
    <?= h($user->firstname) ?>
    //there I am supposed to show the name of the user but I always get 2 errors> Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/Template/Layout/default.ctp, line 49]
    Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object[ APP/Template/Layout/default.ctp, line 49]
    <!--En of test-->

    <a href="logout">Se déconnecter</a>
    <?php else: ?>
    <li class="right"><a href="register"><button id="register">S'enregistrer</button></a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="login"><button id="login">Connexion</button></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm lost and I don't see why the user is not considered as a variable?
thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Have you passed variable `$user` from your controller to view page?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051022/how-do-i-access-a-logged-in-users-phone-number-in-cakephp/38067309#38067309

Comment: @ShaunakShukla what do yo mean by "passed the variable $user from your controller to view page?" ??? I did not add anything in these pages since I didn't know what could help :(

Comment: @ManoharKhadka I tried it but i have a other error: Deprecated (16384): SessionHelper has been deprecated. Use request->session() instead. [CORE/src/View/Helper/SessionHelper.php, line 39]                    with this line adapted <?php $firstname = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.firstname');
?>

Comment: @moimoimoi, use `$this->request->session()->read('firstname')`

Comment: @ShaunakShukla thank you for the help...but it's still not working but the positive thing is that I do not have an error anymore.

Comment: By default when a user logged in, cakephp put user data in session, all you have to do is access that user session.

Comment: @Amir We did not stock the data in sessions, to be honest we made it differently I think it's with Auth.

Comment: Why reinventing a wheel? cakephp manages user sessions well enough. Have a look at it.

Comment: @Amir I did not have the choice, everything was already developped by an other developer and we are both new to developpement and cakephp :(

Comment: Once I had to use mysql procedure with cakephp and no ORM. I had checked username and password exists then assigned those information in cakephp way so that I could use Auth class.

Comment: @Amir Thank you a lot it's working !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact line of codes I have used. You have to change in controller.

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'login';

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->__login_validation($this->request->data)[0] == '') {
            $params = array();
            $params[] = trim($this->request->data['user_name']);
            $pass = trim($this->request->data['user_pass']);
            $user = $this->User->callProcedure('UserGetPass', $params);
            if (!empty($user)) {
                $pass_stored = $user[0]['users']['pass_word'];
                if (empty($user)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Please provide valid username and password');
                } else if (!empty($user)) {
                    $newHash = Security::hash($pass, 'blowfish', $pass_stored);
                    if ($user[0]['users']['username'] != trim($this->request->data['user_name']) || $user[0]['users']['pass_word'] != $newHash) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Please provide valid username and password');
                    } else {
                        $this->request->data = array(
                            'User' => array(
                                'username' => trim($this->request->data['user_name']),
                                'pass_word' => $pass
                            )
                        );
                        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                            $this->__login_insert_history();
                            if ($this->Auth->user('user_type_id') == 99) {
                                $menus = $this->applicant_menu_list();
                            } else {
                                $menus = $this->user_wise_menus($this->Auth->user('id'));
                            }
                            $_SESSION['menus'] = $menus;
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Please provide valid username and password');
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash($this->__login_validation($this->request->data)[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Later you can use Auth class to show user information using

```
 <?php echo $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username') ; ?>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This helped a lot: I only had to add the line you gave me          <?php
 echo $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.firstname');
?>